# Поиск самой длинной повторяющейся поседовательности

Tags: java, алгоритм

У меня есть код, который должен искать самую длинную повторяющуюся последовательность. Но в этой последовательности

> 7888885466662716666

На данный момент он выводит первое вхождение в индекс 1-5 и второе в 2-6, элемент 8. Но должны выводиться 6, так как, это является самой длинной повторяющейся последовательностью. Пыталься сделать по этому алгортиму, но что то запутался)

- Проверьте, повторяется ли первый символ по всей строке, если нет
- Проверьте, повторяются ли 2 начальных символа на всем протяжении,
  если нет
- проверьте, 3

Можете что то подсказать по этому поводу? Или возможно есть какой либо более простой путь?

```
private int element;
    private int lastElement;
    private int length;

    private byte [] readByteFromFile (File name) throws IOException {
        return Files.readAllBytes (name.toPath ());
    }

    private void searchByte (byte [] byteMass) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i <byteMass.length; i ++) {
                int count = 0;
                for (int j = i + 1; j <byteMass.length; j ++) {
                    if (byteMass [i + count] == ​​byteMass [j]) {
                        if (count> = length) {
                            length = count + 1;
                            element = i;
                            lastElement = j - count;
                        }
                        count++;
                    } else {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Уточните, что вы ожидаете и что получаете. Что ожидаете более-менее понятно, но что получаете непонятно совсем. И объясните, почему получаемый результат неверен. На приведенной последовательности правильный результат символ 8 с индексами 1-5.

Comment: получаю я элемент 8, его первое вхождение в индксе 1, второй в 2 и длина 4. Но должна быть последовательность 6 так как, она повторяется дважды в отличии от последовательности 8, соответсвенно 8 не является самой длиной повторяющайся последовательностью ( а просто самой длинной последовательностью) в отличии от 6, кои являются самой длинной повторяющайся последовательностью

Comment: Что такое "повторящаяся последовательность"?

Comment: Последовательность, которая встречается более 1-го раза (2 и более). 8-ки в примере встречаются однажды в отличии от 6 - которые встречаются дважды.

Comment: А почему `6`, а не `7`? Они тоже дважды встречаются

Comment: потому что 7 не самая длинная повторяющаяся

Comment: можно ли использовать HashMap или другие структуры данных ?

Comment: Да, можно использовать

Comment: Нужно найти символ, который встречается чаще остальных? Напишите какая «последовательность» в Вашем примере самая длинная, именно, покажите из чего она состоит.

Comment: 6666 так как она встречается более одного раза, что делает ее самой длинной повторяющайся последовательностью

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял путаное объяснение, то  для решения задачи нужно построить суффиксный массив и сравнить соседние суффиксы (они упорядочены по алфавиту) на совпадение префиксов (задача LCP, можно решать алгоритмом Касаи).

Если длина последовательности невелика, то можно решать и в лоб - проверять все подпоследовательности длиной 1..N/2 (если пересечение недопустимо) на повторное вхождение (процесс может быть ускорен с использованием бинарного поиска по длине подпоследовательности)

Answer (score 0):

и правда, вопрос не совсем понятен,
  быть может вам поможет такой код?

```
  String x = "7888885466662716666";
  int start = 0;
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i = 1; i <= x.length(); i++){
      if (i == x.length() || x.charAt(i-1) != x.charAt(i) ){
          list.add(x.substring(start, i));
          start = i;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
```

он разделяет строку на серии из повторяющихся символов и кладет каждую в отдельную ячейку массива
дальше с ними можно делать что угодно